# Continuos location tracking in web application

Tags: web-applications, geolocation, gps

I have been researching the ability to make a sportstracker (continous GPS tracking) as a web-app/PWA, but this still seems impossible.

I have made one that somehow works, by using the Wake Lock API which works on Android, not iOS, but it still seem flaky and does turn off the screen ocasionally and javascript and tracking stop.

A web worker does not allow GPS tracking as far as I can tell.

I am totally fine with user consent and icons, bells and whistles that tells the user that tracking is going on. And battery drain should not be a bigger issue than it is on native apps for this use case.

Is there any way around this in 2022?

Comment: Did you find a way to this?

Comment: No, it still seems impossible.
I don't understand it. Of course there should be bells and whistles to let the user know. But it's weird that it is not possible to do any kind of useful sport-trackers.
I don't get the privacy argument, since it is possible in native apps.